# Calculating amount of Jam labels - negative values and roundup/down - excell/GSheets

Tags: excel-formula

I'm struggling with the little excel knowledge I have to calculate the number of boxes of labels I need based on amount produced.
c5 amount produced. (any)
a8 number of labels in a box. (1,800)
b8 cost per box (any)
d8 number of labels left over if less than amount produced. Otherwise display 0.  I am using `=IF(A8-C5<=0, 0, A8-C5)` but if I `c5>a8` I get a negative value ?

e8 = number of box(s) needed.  Only display if greater than 1 and round up to the next integer. Otherwise display 0. I am using `=IF(D8=0,, (C5/A8))` but need to merge this with something like `=IF(e8 > 0, ROUNDDOWN(e8, 0), ROUNDUP(e8, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

into d8 I put =IF(C5A8, A8-C5,0)) and in e8 =IF(C5>A8/2,(ROUNDUP(C5/A8)),0) much more accurate.